# Remotely launching a process with LLDB

Tags: lldb

I'm trying to remotely launch and debug a new process with `lldb` without much success.

Attaching to an already launched process works well by running these commands:

```
process connect <url>
process attach -P gdb-remote --pid <pid>
```

But if I want `debugserver` to launch the executable by itself I'm running into troubles. Especially, I have no clue what arguments should I pass to `target create`.

According to [this page](https://lldb.llvm.org/remote.html) LLDB "will transparently take care of [..] downloading the executable in order to be able to debug", yet `target create` seem to always require a local file. If I specify the remote file via `-r` I get either `unable to open target file` or `remote --> local transfer without local path is not implemented yet` errors. If I set the target to a local file (such as a local copy of the remote's loader executable) without using `-r`, then attempt to run `process launch -p gdb-remote -s <remote path>` LLDB will attempt running the local path on the remote machine and fail.

What are the correct commands I need to use in order to launch a remote process?

Comment: Greg just added a bunch more details to the remote debugging page you cited.  See if that makes things clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After contacting LLDB's mailing list Greg updated [the documentation page](http://lldb.llvm.org/remote.html), which now clearly explains what I have to do (Specifically I was missing the `script` lines, which appear to be the correct way to set the remote executable path)